# SkLearn SVM - How to get multiple predictions ordered by probability?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am doing some text classification.
Let's say I have 10 categories and 100 "samples", where each sample is a sentence of text. I have split my samples into 80:20 (training, testing) and trained the SVM classifier:

```
text_clf_svm = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words=('english'),ngram_range=(1,2))), ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                         ('clf-svm', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2', random_state=42, learning_rate='adaptive', eta0=0.9))])

# Fit training data to SVM classifier, predict with testing data and print accuracy
text_clf_svm = text_clf_svm.fit(training_data, training_sub_categories)
```

Now when it comes to predicting, I do not want just a single category to be predicted. I want to see, for example, a list of the "top 5" categories for a given unseen sample as well as their associated probabilities:

```
top_5_category_predictions = text_clf_svm.predict(a_single_unseen_sample)
```

Since `text_clf_svm.predict` returns a value which represents the index of the categories available, I want to see something like this as output:

`[(4,0.70),(1,0.20),(7,0.04),(9,0.06)]`

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: `predict_proba` will do *part* of the job (i.e. not the sorting part), but it can be used only with `log` and `modified_huber` loss, and not with `hinge` (i.e. SVM); see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.predict)

Answer (score 1):

This is something I had used a while back for a similar problem:

```
probs = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
# Sort desc and only extract the top-n
top_n_category_predictions = np.argsort(probs)[:,:-n-1:-1]
```

This will give you the top n categories for each sample.

If you also want to see the probabilities corresponding to these categories, then you can do:

```
top_n_probs = np.sort(probs)[:,:-n-1:-1]
```

> Note: Here `X_test` is of shape `(n_samples, n_features)`. So make sure you use your `single_unseen_sample` in the same format.